# ASP.Net MVC - How can a button access url query string parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I'm working on a password reset project.

Users are sent an email with a url like:
mysite.com/ResetPass?id=10&token=233rgths567sdsfg

This contains a user Id and JWT token in the url as parameters.

The MVC controller shows the password reset page.

```
        [HttpGet("ResetPass")]

        public IActionResult ResetPass([FromQuery] int id, [FromQuery] string token)
        {
            // How to send the id and token from the Url query string to the Button???

            return View("ResetPass");
        }


        // Reset Password Button
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassButton()
        {
             // How to access the user id and token?
        }
```

I want to have a form on this page that allows users to change their password then send the new password, user Id and token to the API for processing.

But how do I get the variables from the url (the user id and token) to the button?

Do I just use Viewbag and pass them to the page?
Or is there a way for the button to just access the Url query string?

Comment: Access the `Request` in the controller (although in this case the token is *already bound* to parameter .. so why the question at all?) and extract the parameters / build the models / run the logic. Pass the relevant models / values to views. (How they are supplied — ViewBag, TempData, Model etc — is a separate concern.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reset password model and pass this model around. Example:

```
public class ResetPasswordModel
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Token { set; get; }
}
```

Then:

```
    public IActionResult ResetPass([FromQuery] int id, [FromQuery] string token)
    {
        var model = new ResetPasswordModel {
           Id = id,
           Token = token,
        }

        return View("ResetPass", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassButton(ResetPasswordModel model)
    {
         // do something with model
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Adlorem, I'll give it a try.

Comment: When I do the above the model.Id and model.Token in ResetPassButton is null. Do I have to do something on the ResetPass.cshtml webpage?

Comment: I added in invisible fields into the form then grabbed them from within ResetPassButton() Form - @Html.Hidden("FormToken", Model.Token) Button Method - string token = Request.Form["FormToken"]

Comment: You dont have to use form. I updated my answer. You can use action link unless you intend to user antiforgerytoken.  I think its much simpler approach, but you must remove anti forgery token validation from controller.